# What are the basic steps from a hardware circuit to a transitionssystem

Tags: logic, computer-science, transition, boolean-logic

What are the basic steps when I want to get a hardware circuit into a transitionssystem? I don't get the arrows between the nodes. The arrows from/to the same node are simple. But How do I get the arrows between node {r} and node {x,r,y} for example? and what can I write on these arrows for better readability?

[image: Transitionssystem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) has one state bit and one output bit. Therefore you can distinguish four different `r/y` states:

```
r  y
----
0  0
0  1
1  0
1  1
```

From each of these states the machine will transition to a subsequent state depending on the input bit `x`. This can be described as a table again:

```
r  y  | x | r' y'
------+---+------
0  0  | 0 | 0  1
0  0  | 1 | 1  0
------+---+------
0  1  | 0 | 0  1
0  1  | 1 | 1  0
------+---+------
1  0  | 0 | 1  0
1  0  | 1 | 1  1
------+---+------
1  1  | 0 | 1  1
1  1  | 1 | 1  1
------+---+------
```

From this table you can derive the state transition diagram:

[image]

**To answer your question:**
The state transition arcs are labeled with the condition under which this transition takes place.
The diagram is not complete, unless every conceivable combination of input values is taken into consideration. Do you find the missing label in my diagram?

Note that state `0/0` is unreachable. No arrows are pointing to this state.

State `1/1` is a terminal state. It cannot be left, once it is reached.

Look [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Seq/fsm.html) for a nice lecture note on *Finite State Machines with Output (Mealy and Moore Machines)*